# Help: need a compact shunt resistor for current measurement

Tags: shunt

I'm very new to electronics and learning as I am working on a project. I am trying to find a small compact replacement for the very large shunt that comes with a Current Meter I bought on ebay. Can anyone advise me on how to calculate an appropriate shunt resistor (ohms & power rating)?

These are the Current Meters I bought:
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-50A-100V-Dual-LED-Digital-Voltmeter-Ammeter-Amp-Volt-Meter-Current-Shunt-/281587980311?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item418ff39817

I am wanting to measure the following...

- Capacity in Battery-A  (Lipo 4000mAh 3s 11.1v)
- Capacity in Battery-B  (Lipo 4000mAh 3s 11.1v)
- Total draw of entire unit

I was hoping to achieve this with the 3 meters from eBay but my application only draws a small fraction of the current these meters can display.

My project is building a compact Ground Station (which is all contained in a suitcase being powered by 2x 11.1v Lipo 3 cell batteries with a SPDT toggle switch to flip between the power sources), and I think the power requirements of the system is up to 20 Watts. All this to run an FPV RC plane.

Can anyone help me out? I am hoping someone can suggest a suitable shunt replacement.

Thanks very much,
Nick.

Comment: Yup, that shunt looks the appropriate size for 50A.

Comment: A link to ebay is crappy - find the pdf data sheet and link to that. If it aint got a data sheet then you're going to find it hard to make comparisons on techy stuff. My rule: Only buy EE stuff (including resistors, caps etc.) that have a data sheet. Only buy from reputable sources. Regard this as something I've learnt along the way. It might be the best advice you'll get all week.

Comment: What's the max current draw of your RC plane?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams... that is GOOD advice. Thank you, I will definitely do this from now on. Allot invested in this thing so don't want to buy substandard stuff. So the shunt size is correct?? It seems very large and I'm weirdly uncomfortable with it being so exposed. Is this normal?
This is more compact... https://www.bluesea.com/products/9228/Analog_Meter_Shunt_-_50A (there is a tech drawing as well on the link). Thanks

Comment: @Techydude... I'm unsure at the moment, I'm still putting it all together. I think it will be around 15-20W when I totall all the devices going in up. I'm doing my best to try and learn all this as I go without breaking things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so the size of the current-measurement shunt is largely about how much current your circuit draws.  the current meter works by assuming a shunt of a specific resistance, so that when a specific (maximum) current goes thru it, a specific voltage will be dropped across it (simple Ohms Law, V = I * R), with a certain degree of error according to the tolerance of the shunt resistor.

so for example, a 12V battery driving a 10ohm load = 1.2Amps, & therefore the power delivered to the load P = V*I = 14.4 Watts.  to make a decent measure of that current without the shunt resistor having too much of a negative impact on the voltage seen by your load, you'd probably want a shunt resistor of about one hundredth - say, 100 milli-ohms, and with 1.2 Amps flowing through that it'll drop 120mV - that's the voltage your "amp meter" is measuring and showing as being "1.2 amps".  but only when you use a shunt of 0.1ohms (100mohms), because that's what the meter is calibrated for.

the "problem" with shunt resistors is that they dissipate heat, because they're a simple resistor & you're measuring the voltage dropped across it as a result of the current passing through it.  the power absorbed by the shunt P = (I^2)*R (I-squared x R).  So the power dissipated in the shunt goes up with the *square* of the current.

so for that 50 Amp shunt example you gave, even though I don't know its resistance (it can't be gleaned from that ebay page), that's a lot of amps!  so it'll get hot.  which means it needs to be big enough to dissipate that heat without destroying itself.

that's why I asked you how much current you're expecting to draw.  I'm concerned by your answer, because I asked you what the max current might be, and you gave me an answer in watts - power.  let's say it's 1.6 amps.  that's not much compared to the 50 amps of the shunt example you've given.  like, 10 times higher measuring capability.

so yes, doing some figures in my head, you could get away with a somewhat smaller shunt, because your currents are less than 1/10th of what that shunt is capable. the trouble now is, not knowing the resistance of that shunt, nor what the range of shunt-voltage that amp-meter is expecting to measure, I can't advise you on what ohm your shunt needs to be to work with that meter.  until we know that, it's almost impossible to point you at something specific.  but generally speaking, at the current you're suggesting, a simple 1 watt resistor with 1% tolerance, of some ohms, is probably all you need.

but my bigger questions are:  why 3 meters?  if you're manually switching between 2 batteries with a switch, in which case only 1 is ever being used at any given time, why not just have 1 meter?  and, what value is the voltage & current reading to a user of this thing?  why do they need to know voltage & current draw of this system, and are they expected to know that 9.0 V means the 3-cells-in-series battery is almost flat, and that 12.6 is fully charged?  why not just have a few LEDs showing battery state based on crude voltage measurements?

Comment: wow that was a great answer and thank you VERY much for taking the time to raise your concerns and they are very valid. I'm rethinking a few things now and also clearly I need to do some numbers in order to better understand what I need. I will definitely poke this thread again soon when I have more precise information to respond. Thanks again for your support! Cheers

Comment: you're welcome. would appreciate if you could mark the question as answered :)

Comment: In the interests of using the meters you already have, you need to do one of: (a) measure the resistance of that 50A shunt, but that would require a very expensive multimeter that can measure down to a milliohm or better, but in reality a 50A shunt is gonna be probably 1 milliohm (50A through 1mohm = 2.5 Watts, sounds about right for that shunt); or (b) based on my (a) guestimate that corresponds to 50mV = 50Amps, so set up a voltage source (PSU or battery) and get a couple of 1% or better resistors in series (i.e. a voltage divider) to create your own 50mV & see what the meter reads.

Comment: So with a 5.0V supply, and a 100kohm in series with 1kohm to ground, you should see approximately 50mV between ground & the junction between those 2 resistors. Connect the meter's 2 shunt connection wires to these 2 points, and it'll either read 50A, or tell you how far off we are & thus re-calculate to work out what its full-scale is, & thus what milli-ohms the shunt needs to be (recalculated for your 1 or 2 amps, instead of 50 amps.